# When the content of the ListView doesn't exceed the viewPort,(which means it's not scrollable yet), RefreshIndicator isn't available

Tags: flutter

I have RefreshIndicator, there's a ListView inside。When the content of the ListView doesn't exceed the viewPort,(which means it's not scrollable yet), RefreshIndicator isn't available。
Amazingly, RefreshIndicator works when I remove the `controller` and `physics`
But my code has to listen on _scrollController, so it can't be deleted, so is there any other solution

```
child: RefreshIndicator(
          color: WColors.theme_color,
          child: ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            shrinkWrap: false,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              if (datas == null || datas.length == 0) {
                return Container(
                  height: pt(400),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: datas == null
                      ? CupertinoActivityIndicator()
                      : Text(
                          res.allEmpty,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                        ),
                );
              } else {
                if (index != datas.length) {
                  return TodoItem(
                    index,
                    datas[index],
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: pt(45),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: (currentPage < totalPage)
                        ? CupertinoActivityIndicator()
                        : Text(
                            res.isBottomst,
                            style: TextStyle(color: WColors.hint_color),
                          ),
                  );
                }
              }
            },
            itemCount:
                (datas == null || datas.length == 0) ? 1 : datas.length + 1,
          ),
          onRefresh: _refreshAuto),
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the `RefreshIndicator` always , even when your List is small, you just have to replace the `physics` you are using by `AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()`.

```
ListView.builder(
            controller: _scrollController,
            physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics()
            shrinkWrap: false,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
```